# using shared preferences for retrieving data

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I have an age input edit text which i want to put user's previous input there using shared preferences (for after first input). i have written following code but it force closes. what is the problem??

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//setting text for editText
age_editText.setText(my_prefs.getInt("age_value", 0) + ""); //when i delete this part, it doesn't force close

btn_calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age_editText.getText().toString());
                    //shared preferences
                    sharedPreferences my_prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = my_prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt("age_value", age_value);
                    editor_bmi.commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.please_fill_all_inputs), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: post your log cat error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
sharedPreferences my_prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
sharedPreferences my_prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and write this above

```
age_editText.setText(my_prefs.getInt("age_value", 0) + "");
```

**proper Way to do That.**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    sharedPreferences my_prefs getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    age_editText.setText(my_prefs.getInt("age_value", 0) + ""); //when i delete this part, it doesn't force close

    btn_calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                Int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age_editText.getText().toString());

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = my_prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt("age_value", age_value);
                editor_bmi.commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.please_fill_all_inputs), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `sharedPreferences my_prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

You missed `=` to create an object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getSharedPreferences()` in place of `getPreferences()` as shown below.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**Note:** `getPreferences()` and `getSharedPreferences()` are two different methods that return different Preference objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your age into SharedPreferences by using below method :

```
public void saveAge(int age_value) {
        SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("my_age", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pre.edit();
        editor.putInt("age_value", age_value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

And when you want to get your age, use this :

```
public int readAge() {
        SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("my_age", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int age = pre.getInt("age_value", 0);
        return age;
    }
```